# How to add a second group legend in ggplot (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, legend

As you can see from the graph below, ggplot automatically change the graphs color based on a second group division (literally `group2`).
Now, what I am not able to do is to print a legend for it. I would like under gender with their respective color to be added `group2` legend with their respective color or maybe just to manually label them as such.

```
set.seed(34)
data <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("female", "male"), length.out=10),
    group2 = sample(letters[1:2], 10, replace = T),
    group = rep(letters[11:13], length.out=10),
    nums = as.integer(runif(10, min=10, max=500)))

xc <- data %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(sum=sum(nums)) %>%
    group_by(gender, group2, group) %>%
    mutate(prop = nums/sum*100)

ggplot(xc, aes(x=group, fill = gender, color = group2, y = prop)) +
    geom_col(position="dodge", color = "white", alpha = 0.85) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#466760","#845574")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme() +
    ggtitle("") +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Percentage %")
```

My plot:

[image: Example Plot]

Comment: Just remove `color = "white"` from `geom_col` and the legend will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve, maybe this approach could be useful:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xc, aes(x = gender, y = prop, fill = group2)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0.01), alpha = 0.85) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#466760", "#845574")) +
  facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 1)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Percentage %")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>